# How to access structure field in function when having matrix of structures which is passed to function in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix

Hey everyone i need some help :(
I have struct in my file like this

```
    typedef struct{
    uint16_t n; //x axis
    uint16_t m; //y axis
    uint8_t value;
    uint8_t finished;
}one_element;
```

Now in main.c i have something like this

```
one_element loaded[8][10];
```

I am passing to function bfs loaded matrix from main like this

```
bfs(loaded);
```

And my bfs function is declared like this:

```
void bfs(one_element* loaded[]);
```

And in bfs function i want to set field for specific struct at some position, for example 0 and 0 (top left element)

```
one_element from_queue;
from_queue = ((*getFromQueue)(&myQueue));
loaded[from_queue.m][from_queue.n].finished = 1;
```

I now for sure that indexes are good (from_queue.m and from_queue.n) i checked that in debbuger, also i dont have any errors, but i got segmentation fault when executing

```
loaded[from_queue.m][from_queue.n].finished = 1;
```

So what is problem, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks 
PS: This is first problem for which i had to made account :D I hope someone can help :D

Comment: Check your complier warnings. That should be a major clue.

Comment: Thanks you John Bollinger i dont know why i could not see what i was doint wrong